# Is $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x^2-y^3)$ regular local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be field,  and $A:=k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x^2-y^3). $

Now, $A$ is 1-dimension Noetherian local normal domain.

In general, 1-dimension Noetherian local domain is DVR iff normal.

So I think $A$ is DVR, in particular regular local.

What is my mistake?

Comment: It isn't normal.

Comment: Noetherianness and locality are almost trivially satisfied. So looking more closely at normality might be a good first thing to do.

Comment: @Ryu as I said at the other question, you need a variety that is normal but not nonsingular.

Comment: Um, a bit of an oddity, but when I checked just now, the database DID NOT say it was not regular.  The question mark means "unknown."  But, considering the answer given I will definitely be updating it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element $T = x/y$ in the fraction field of $A$ satisfies
$$
T^3 - x = 0,
$$
but $T$ is not in $A$. Therefore $A$ is not integrally closed in its fraction field and is not normal.

Comment: Thank you very much.